# kafka consumer in shell script

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am newbie in Kafka. I want to consume remote kafka message in shell script. Basically I have linux machine where I cannot run any web server (some strange reasons) only thing I can do is use crontab/shell script to listen for kafka message which is hosted remotely. Is it possible to write simple shell script which will consume kafka message, parse it and take corresponding action.

Answer (score 3):

kafka clients are available in multiple languages. you can use any client, you don't need any web server or browser for it.
you may use shell script for consuming message & parsing but that script have to use any kafka client provided [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Clients) because currently there is no client written in pure shell script.
Kafka has provided kafka client console producer and consumer, you can use that as well.

```
 bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --from-beginning
```

follow the [document](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart)  properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the tool `kafkacat` which is documented for example [here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/app-development/kafkacat-usage.html).

This is a very powerful and fast tool to read data out of Kafka from the console and is open source: https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat.

Many exmples are provided on GitHub and one example is shown below:

```
kafkacat -C -b mybroker -t mytopic
```